# How to remove the left "drag bar" in Ctoolbar?

Tags: windows, mfc

How to remove the left "drag bar" in Ctoolbar???  red rect area in the picture below??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include `CBRS_GRIPPER` to the list of styles when you're creating the toolbar. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164052.aspx)

Update: You will have to explicitly remove the `CBRS_GRIPPER` style using the code below, as it is added by the framework automatically:

```
m_wndToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndToolBar.GetPaneStyle() & ~CBRS_GRIPPER);
```

Comment: there is no CBRS_GRIPPER style in my code:
 `if               (!m_wndtoolbar.CreateEx(this,WS_VISIBLE|TBSTYLE_FLAT|CCS_NODIVIDER, WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_ALIGN_TOP,
  CRect(0,0,0,0)) || !m_wndtoolbar.LoadToolBar(IDR_GAME) )
 {
  TRACE0("failed to create toolbar\n");
  return FALSE;
 }`

Comment: Have you tried: m_wndToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndToolBar.GetPaneStyle() & ~CBRS_GRIPPER);

Comment: CBRS_GRIPPER is added automatically. so indeed after creation you have to remove it with SetPaneStyle as previous commenter said.